# Call Functions by String

Tags: ada

Is there any way to call a procedure by its name in a String variable in Ada, as Python does with:

```
def _ssh(hostname, port):
    pass
def _telnet(hostname, port):
    pass 
def _mosh(hostname, port):
    pass
protocols = {
    'ssh': _ssh,
    'mosh': _mosh,
    'telnet': _telnet
}
# call your function by string
hostname = 'localhost'
port = '22'
protocol = 'ssh'
result = protocols[protocol](hostname, port)
```

Answer (score 6):

Well, it’s a bit of work, since you don't have any convenient shorthand for creating maps (a.k.a. dictionaries). This does the job:

```
with Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Ordered_Maps;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Alubio is
```

We need a pointer-to-subprogram to instantiate the Map

```
   type Handler is access procedure (Hostname : String; Port : Integer);
```

A map from string to the pointer-to-subprogram. It needs to be "indefinite" because the type String is indefinite (not fixed-size), and it needs to be "ordered" because we don’t want the bother of declaring hash functions etc.

```
   package Maps is new Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Ordered_Maps
     (Key_Type     => String,
      Element_Type => Handler);
```

I like to declare subprograms before defining them, but it’s not strictly necessary here

```
   procedure Ssh (Hostname : String; Port : Integer);
   procedure Mosh (Hostname : String; Port : Integer);
   procedure Telnet (Hostname : String; Port : Integer);
```

The Map

```
   Map : Maps.Map;
```

The demo subprograms

```
   procedure Ssh (Hostname : String; Port : Integer) is
   begin
      Put_Line ("ssh, " & Hostname & Port'Image);
   end Ssh;

   procedure Mosh (Hostname : String; Port : Integer) is
   begin
      Put_Line ("mosh, " & Hostname & Port'Image);
   end Mosh;

   procedure Telnet (Hostname : String; Port : Integer) is
   begin
      Put_Line ("telnet, " & Hostname & Port'Image);
   end Telnet;

begin
```

Set up the Map

```
   Map.Insert ("ssh", Ssh'Access);
   Map.Insert ("mosh", Mosh'Access);
   Map.Insert ("telnet", Telnet'Access);
```

Call the subprograms via the Map. Not quite sure why the `.all` (dereferencing the pointer-to-subprogram) is needed, you often don’t: here, without it, the compiler says "invalid procedure or entry call", pointing at `Map`.

```
   Map ("ssh").all ("s", 1);
   Map ("mosh").all ("m", 2);
   Map ("telnet").all ("t", 3);

end Alubio;
```

The output:

```
$ ./alubio 
ssh, s 1
mosh, m 2
telnet, t 3
```

Comment: This was my first approach. I'm calling a procedure in a protected object using an access protected procedure type stored in a map. But I am making this call inside another procedure in the same protected object and I obtain a program error in execution time. I suspect that there is a locking limitation here, but I can not understand it. I know this is a different issue. I am trying to find another approach like storing a string instead of an access type.

Comment: Perhaps if you showed us your code (like you really ought to on SO) we could help better. Or told us your actual problem ... it sounds as though you already knew what I showed, so I was wasting my time, which doesn’t encourage me to look any deeper.  That said, could it be that the compiler can’t tell that the actual called procedure is in fact in the same PO?

Comment: Perhaps you are violating 9.5.1 15 of the RM which causes a Program_Error:  an external call on a protected subprogram (or an external requeue) with the same target object as that of the protected action ?

Comment: I will open another Question about calling protected procedures using access types, as it is a different issue/topic. In this Question I only want to know different ways to call a procedure using its name in a `String`. You have contribute with one perfectly valid solution. Maybe there are more.

Answer (score 4):

A simple way is to use an enumerated type and a case statement.

```
type Protocol is (ssh, mosh, telnet);
```

then with a variable `given_protocol : Protocol` :

```
case given_protocol is
  when ssh    => Ssh (Hostname, Port);
  when mosh   => Mosh (Hostname, Port);
  when telnet => Telnet (Hostname, Port);
end case;
```

This avoids access types and maps.

You get `given_protocol` from a String by using the `'Value` attribute: `given_protocol := Protocol'Value (given_string)`.

Comment: Another good solution. Do you know any library for making simple command line interfaces like Cisco routers ones?

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, this is not possible as Ada doesn't store the functions and procedures in a hashmap as Python do.
You can still provide a function taking the string as argument and returning an access to the function that you can call afterwards but I'm not sure that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: This is a valid solution, as Simon's one. But it is not compatible with my real problem in calling a protected procedure from an access type inside another protected procedure in the same object.

Comment: Ok I understand but it wasn't specified in your initial question.